# Format of a date used for initialisation

Tags: vbscript

In a VBScript, I need to initialise a variable with a date. In my country we usually specify a date with this format: day month year

Here is what I'm trying to do in my VBScript:

```
Date = #07-06-1973#
MsgBox FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate)
```

but the date I get is July the 6th, where I was expecting June the 7th!

Now, as it seems the first number represents the month, here is what I tried to do:

```
Date = #13-06-1973#
MsgBox FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate)
```

but now, the first number represents the day! (I get the following date: June the 13th)

I haven't found a way to force the date format, so that there is no more ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, VBScript supports date literals in the US and ISO formats only:

```
' US format:
Date = #10/19/2009#

' ISO format:
Date = #2009-10-19#
```

However, the date separators can be different (slash, dash, space etc), and the VBScript engine also recognizes dates containing abbreviated month names (`#Oct 19, 2009#`) and non-ambiguous dates with swapped date parts (`#2009 19 10#`). The latter explains why `#13-06-1973#` in your second example is recognized as June, 13th: the number 13 falls outside the acceptable range of months (1-12) so it's interpreted as the day part.

If you want to specify dates in your regional format (that is, the format specified in your Regional and Language Options), you can use the [`CDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2.aspx) function to convert date strings, for example:

```
' Russian format
Date = CDate("19.10.2009")
```

But using US and ISO date literals are more reliable and preferred.